# MVC 4 partial view not displaying correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Has anyone seen an ASP.NET MVC 4 partial view render like this before?

[image: Partial View Problem]

Of three development workstations, two display the it correctly, and one does this. Obviously, it is something with the configuration of the third machine, but I cannot seem to figure out what.

Comment: You should show your code.

Comment: @Ek0nomik: I wish I could, but the company I work for is very paranoid about that kind of stuff (witness all the redaction even in the screenshot). I was hoping that someone would recognize this as a known issue from the nature of the result (i.e. <$A$><$B$><$C$>...). If that turns out not to be the case, I will see if I can get clearance to post some portion of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using VS2013 Preview? If so, there was a bug with ASP.NET partial render, try getting a newer version.

Comment: In fact I am! I will update to the RC and see what transpires. Thanks much!

Comment: Yep, that was the culprit. Much appreciated Jacek!

Answer (score 0):

Show your code.

Keep in mind that partial view code has changed from MVC3 to MVC4.

An example would given in your compiler.

Or look here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Like I mentioned above, I would have to get clearance from my company to post any portion of the code. If it comes to that, I will give it a shot, but I honestly don't think the problem is with the code. It works perfectly on every machine except this one. I don't see how it could be anything other than a configuration problem with the machine in question, and I was hoping that someone would recognize it from its effects. Maybe a vain hope, but I thought I would give it a shot...